# how to modify duplicate values

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a workbook with 7531 rows in excel.
There are 3 columns and in 1 column there are duplicate values, I don't want to delete the duplicate value, but I want to modify one so there won't be duplicate values anymore.

Could anyone help me with this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select the range of cells you wish to test. One way to do so is to click on a single cell and then press Ctrl-A.
- On Excel's Home tab, choose Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cells Rules, and then Duplicate Values.
- Click OK within the Duplicate Values dialog box to identify the duplicate values.
- Duplicate values in the list will now be identified.  [image]

Comment: First find duplicate value and after that modify values.